# how to connect hosted server database through local server using php?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i want to connect hosted server database through local server here is my code

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("myserverDbHostname","mydatabaseUsername","Password");
if($con)
{
echo "connect";
mysql_select_db("DatabaseName");
else
{
echo "not connect";
}
?>
```

when i run this file in local server (xammp server) it could n't be connect i get

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to
MySQL server on
```

i get "not connect" response

can any one guide me

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you want to connect to a remote database?

Comment: It sounds like one of `"myserverDbHostname","mydatabaseUsername","Password"` isn't right. The hostName is actually different for a remote connection - did you take that into account?

Comment: hey thanks for response yes i need to connect remote database

Comment: i copy the database host name (remote database host ) and past to local file

Comment: if you want the remote database to apear in your local phpmyadmin you have to make sme changes in config.inc then provide all the details in(connect.php) where you want to set the connection to remote database... but important point is that the remote database allow connections from outside or not you have to varify it first

Comment: hey @UmairIqbal thanks for response can you tell how could i check remote database allow connection from out side.

Comment: You have to contact the database admin to provide rights to access the db from some remote location and grant you the permissions. I don't think if can varify it using coding

Comment: when i check this file another server(host server) it's working fine.i think only it's not working local (xammp server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a three things you need to connect to a remote database:

- port 3306 open on the firewalls. Firewalls in server and client must open port 3306!
- in my.cnf bind-address = 0.0.0.0 to let mysql bind to all interfaces
- sufficient privileges in the database to allow remote connections

Virtual all hosting companies close port 3306 on the firewall, and do not allow direct remote access. And even if they do, you won't get privileges to connect to a database.

Only if the remote database is in your LAN, or you are using a VPS with root access you can configure things to make a remote connection.

Comment: i am checking in my mac system through wifi connction

Comment: what about reverse? Connecting database on local system by php file on server? How can that be done?