# Connecting to a web-hosted database with java

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, jdbc

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to connect our Java Project to a SQLite database with jdbc.
We've been using a database.db file located in the main/resources folder for a while without any issues. Now we're trying to switch to a hosted database, because this project is intended for multiple users and so far, we've had to include the database.db file with every git commit.
So, the most obvious first choice would be to instead of using the local resource, link to a hosted file. We have hosted our database.db file on a public server (yeah, yeah, but data security is not relevant for this project) and changed the resource to the hosted file, but it doesn't seem to work and returns "Resource not found" errors. We can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's what we have:

```
[...]        

public Connection connectOrCreateDatabase(String databaseName) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

               Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:http://server.com/"+databaseName+".db");

[...]
```

Is there any way to get this to work?
Or is http just not supported at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hope this helps... make sure you don't have spaces in your url

[check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436146/how-to-connect-to-local-host-using-jdbc)

this also might be useful...

[check this out too...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367007/how-to-connect-hosted-server-database-through-local-server-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use it over HTTP and pretend it's on the file system.

Why? You can read the db file over HTTP, but you can't write to it, making inserts and updates impossible.

You need to set it up in server mode and connect to it like a "real" database.